# Assign lead to vendor?

Tags: vtiger

I want to know how to assign leads to vendor. Actually i have a vendor who provide  transportation services. So, I want to assign leads to the transport vendor.

Please help me to achieve this in the vtiger. Let me know if there is alternate way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/comment/1173978#Comment_1173978) is the answer.

right now there is no support like what i want in vtiger but always alternate solution exists.

so just posting here so it would be helpful for others.